# Jquery no works into wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I use wordpres and by default load the library of the core of jquery load it´s this :

js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.8.3

When i go for insert my own script of jquery the result it´s no works , things very easy as this code for example no works :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#header_sun").fadeIn(4000).delay(4000).fadeOut(4000);
$("body").css("background","#C3DAEC");

});
```

The example of my code only works if i put in the head of wordpress this :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If i put this code until the core jquery of wordpress all my scripts created in jquery works and if no put this no works , i don´t understand why happen this because the jquery i put until of jquery version of core it´s the same but the version minimun

It´s very strange this i try all and don´t understand why no works ok my code and only works if i put or i call the remote library of jquery and no works with the load jquery of wordpress

Regards !

Comment: Am I right, that you are trying to load jquery through wordpress AND by inserting your own script tag?

Comment: Find the browser's JavaScript error console. What errors do you see there?

Comment: Please look at the related questions on the right side of this  page. This has been asked many times before, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744348/jquery-not-working-in-wordpress. jQuery runs in [`.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode in WordPress.

Comment: Yes i create separated document of jquery and put my script and use for load wp_enqueue_script , i see into the DOM and load perfect and only owrks if i put until the remote load of jquery and if no put this no works

Comment: Type `jQuery` into the javascript console in firebug or chrome web inspector and see if it is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that your code is conflicted by jquery in wp-head()

insert this code in **functions.php**

```
function fix_noconflict() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery' , 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts' , 'fix_noconflict' );
```

Comment: if it's ok please give me a (+)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with Wordpress, but I believe it loads its own version of jQuery in "no conflict" mode, which means that you can't use the `$` shorthand for `jQuery` (there are other JavaScript frameworks which also use `$`). What you can do is use an immediately invoked function expression to allow you to do that, though:

```
(function($) {
    // $ refers to jQuery only inside here
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#header_sun").fadeIn(4000).delay(4000).fadeOut(4000);
        $("body").css("background","#C3DAEC");
    });
})(jQuery);
```

This is the same as the syntax used when developing jQuery plugins, since you can't guarantee that `$` will refer to `jQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery("#header_sun").fadeIn(4000).delay(4000).fadeOut(4000);
   jQuery("body").css("background","#C3DAEC");
});
```

Because, there may be more `libraries` like `prototype`,`mootools`,etc.
used in `wordpress` so there can be confliction of `$`.

Comment: I try this and nothing only works if i put in the head and until the jquery library load default this <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script> no works nothing with the jquery library load with wordpress by default

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in your debugger console, I'd imagine you're getting a 'jQuery is not defined' error?

If so, it sounds like a conflict issue with jQuery, as Wordpress loads jQuery too using no conflict. Using $ instead of jQuery could cause issues with other librares which also use the $. You will need to add a no conflict function, then place your jQuery within it.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    //You can use $ here.
  });
})(jQuery);
// If you have any, your other non jQuery code which uses $ also, can go after here as normal.
```